# Decrypt a string in python using dictionary

Tags: python, encryption, python-3.7

I want to make an encryption-decryption software and for some reason the following command isn't working. I want it to decrypt a parameter called e-text which is actually a string.

I have the exact same code for my encryption algorithm just with a different dictionary and a different set of letters

```
def decrypt(e_text):
    letter = ["#""%""{""}""?""^""(""]"")""[""p""$""+", "=""/""@""*""!""_""-"".""9""8""~""&"">""|"]
    dictionary = {
        "#": "a",
        "%": "b",
        "{": "c",
        "}": "d",
        "?": "e",
        "^": "f",
        "(": "g",
        "]": "h",
        ")": "i",
        "[": "j",
        "p": "k",
        "$": "l",
        "+": "m",
        "/": "n",
        "=": "o",
        "@": "p",
        "*": "q",
        "!": "r",
        "-": "s",
        "_": "t",
        ".": "u",
        "9": "v",
        "8": "w",
        "~": "x",
        "&": "y",
        ">": "z",
        "|": " ",
    }
    for letter in e_text:
        print(dictionary[letter], end='')
```

Comment: Is output not correct ? What do you mean by not working ?

Comment: I don't think you need the `letter` declaration below `def decrypt(e_text)`. Also, I see the list missing commas between elements (if it were intended to be a list).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
"not working" is not a problem description.

Comment: I hope you are doing this "to see if you can", it sounds like you're describing a simple caeser cipher, one of the easiest to break "encryption" schemes in existence.  Please do not use something like this for production use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you didn't show the e_text you want to decrypt, so I'll just assume you meaned the list called "letter".
Just to mention, it's not a good idea to call two different variables the same ('letter').

The for loop in the end takes an element from the list. The elements of your list called "letter" are this two:

```
"#""%""{""}""?""^""(""]"")""[""p""$""+"

"=""/""@""*""!""_""-"".""9""8""~""&"">""|"
```

For the use of your dictionary, you need one string, not a list of 2 strings:

```
letter = "".join(letter)
```

and you get

```
 #%{}?^(])[p$+=/@*!_-.98~&>|
```

If you had a parametr for the decrypt function in this form:

```
text_to_decrypt = "#""%""{""}"
```

you wouldn't need the transformation to one string and you just can call the function, for example:

```
text_to_decrypt = "#""%""{""}"
decrypt(text_to_decrypt)
```

Much better than print() function would be to use return:

```
e_text = "".join(e_text)
# use only if you have the format of "e_text" as of the "letter" list (list of more strings)

solution = []
for letter in e_text:
    solution.append(dictionary[letter])
return solution
```

The same:

```
solution = ""
for letter in e_text:
    solution += dictionary[letter]
return "".join(solution)
```